# Visible Light Communication with Android camera Approach

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-camera, javacv

I have a circle which changes colors according to a data encoding scheme. For example I want to encode the message "Hello" in the color changes of that circle. That means something like a transition from red to green(the color of the filled circle changes from red to green) can be decoded as a binary 1 and a transition from a green to blue can be decoded as a 0. So my message can be encoded in such a format. This part that is my transmitter is ready.

Now I want to be able to receive this encoded data with image processing algorithms using the Android camera. I am new to image processing and after a bit of research I have found that I can use OpenCV or JavaCV for my application. Which one you suggest I should use and what is the apporoach I should follow? I have been able to create an application which can detect circles at real time. However I am not being able to think what to do next.
I followed the color_blob_detection example from opencv examples and i know how to detect a particular color in a frame.

Here, I'm getting confused.

1. Should I keep checking for the three colors red, green, blue in all the frames? Is there a way to determine the percentage of the same in each of the frame so that I can compare the percentages with two successive frames and say that there has been a transition?**
2. Should I buffer a few number of frames in a frame buffer of say a 500 frames and then start processing my frames one by one from the buffer.This can be considered in order to increase the frame rate since in this case my onPreviewFrame() method code will be reduced to a minimum.**

Please suggest how I should go about it ? The transmitter will keep on sending the same message again and again and I don't mind fixing the number of bits/bytes which I'm sending. I just need to identify an 'ID' which is being transmitted in such a manner.

Comment: thanks for the edit Michael..

Comment: Help me on this to achieve the same implementation. My use case is to read a data encoded(numbers) from the camera's flash light .

Answer (score 0):

I am really confused with your first question. Is computing percentage of certain color not image processing? Why do you think that checking for the three colors may be more expensive?

Regarding the second question, the desired frame rate depend on your protocol. If the transitions happen at 10 Hz, you only need 10 FPS to decipher them.

On the other hand, it is possible to copy frame data aside and process it in a queue in a separate thread, so that onPreviewFrame() cycle (which is the Android app main thread) is not stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes checking dor percentages indeed would be image processing, I just wanted to know how it can be achieved with opencv. Secondly yes I do think checking for all the three colors will be expensive because the same procedure has to be repeated for all the three colors. Don't you think it will be expensive?

Comment: @Alex Cohn, Can you give me the overview of the LED data conversion to be handled in Receiver end.. I found some snippet from the below link for receiver end..where the ndk code is in-complete..  It's grateful, if you suggest me to execute the receiver ndk code from the pdf https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=5759370596b7e49f4d75ff68&assetKey=AS%3A370999498428416%401465464581089

Comment: @SenthilMg I am afraid this is not a question that I can answer standing on one foot :(